# How to integrate MS HealthVault service with cordova?

Tags: cordova, oauth

Is it possible to connect to MS HealthVault from Cordova app using MS HealthVault login(OAuth) ?  Could you please share some links/docs about it ?

I was already reading the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863179.aspx  and checking it feasibility to integrate with cordova.

Thanks in-advance

Comment: Have you been able to make headway with this? It is precisely what I am looking into.